# Web Socket & Netty - Received Message Type on messageReceived

Tags: websocket, netty

I'm trying the Netty's WebSocketServer([Netty WebSocketServer](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocket/package-summary.html)). I want to send messages to this server from a native web socket client(from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm) with a code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebSocketTest()
{
  if ("WebSocket" in window)
  {
     alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
     // Let us open a web socket
     var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3210/websocket");
     ws.onopen = function()
     {
        // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
        ws.send("Message to send");
        alert("Message is sent...");
     };
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     { 
        var received_msg = evt.data;
        alert("Message is received...");
     };
     ws.onclose = function()
     { 
        // websocket is closed.
        alert("Connection is closed..."); 
     };
  }
  else
  {
     // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
     alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sse">
   <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However in the handler's messageReceived method, it sees the incoming message in BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer type.

What do I need to change in server code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which browser are you using?

The code in Netty 3.2 supports HyBi-00. Most browsers have moved on from that version. See [post](http://netty.io/blog/2011/11/17/).

Netty 3.3 (3.2 branch of the source) and 4.0 (master branch of the source) contains support for the latest web socket standards (RFC 6455).

My recommendation is to use netty 3.2 branch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've downladed the source and I'm trying to build via maven but it asks me "GPG Passphrase" I couldn't find any info about it. do you know the passphrase? or what should I do?

Comment: I think you may be accidentally trying to deploy it.  Try mvn jar or mvn package.

Comment: yeap it works with mvn package. however I'm still getting BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer. By the way, I'm using chromium 14.0.835.202 (Developer Build 103287 Linux) and I've downloaded https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2

Comment: You need to use the WebSocketX package. Try running the example https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that netty's stable release doesn't support the newer websocket versions used by browsers. You might want to check if websocket connection is being established successfully.